# Finding conditional probability of continous r.v

Tags: probability

[image]

### Attempt

Since we can write $f_{XY}(x,y)=f(x)g(y)$, then $X$ and $Y$ are independent, and hence

$$ P(Y<X | X=1/3) = P(Y<X) $$

Now, the region $ \{y<x\} $ with region given by density function is a triangle which we break in two. Thus

$$ P(Y<X) = \int_0^{1/2} \int_0^x f_{XY} (x,y) dydx + \int_0^{1/2} \int_0^{1-x} f_{XY} (x,y) dxdy $$

now, solving this integrals give me $0.5$. The answer key gives $\boxed{0.25}$ as an answer. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrongly assume that $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ can be written as a product $f(x)g(y)$.

There is a condition $0<y<1-x$ by the description of the PDF which makes this impossible.

$X$ and $Y$ are definitely not independent in this case. Note e.g. that $Y<1-X$ a.s. so the values that can be taken by $Y$ **depend** on the value taken by $X$.